# Query a double foreign key and display in template

Tags: python, templates, django-models, foreign-keys

Models:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
patientID = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='Insert PatientID')
birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD')
gender = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=Gender_Choice, default='UNDEFINED')

class Examination(models.Model):
number_of_examination = models.IntegerField()
patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_of_examination = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD')

class GeneralData(models.Model):
examination = models.ForeignKey(Examination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
height = models.FloatField(default='-', help_text= '[m] not [cm]! ')
weight = models.FloatField(default='-', help_text= '[kg]')
aha_classification = models.IntegerField(choices=AHA_CHOICES, default=0)
```

My Problem: 
I don't know how to query the general data object with the number of examination = 1 for one special patient. I want to display the object on the detail page of the patient. I can query on the Examination class without problems. But then I just don't know how to query the generaldata object. The detail page loads only the Patient model. Due to this I have to query from the Patient model over the Examination model to the Generaldata model right? Or is it possible to load other models in the template? Thanks for your help!

Got it!
Added to my DetailView:

```
def DetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Patient
template_name = 'app/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet
    context['FirstGeneral'] = GeneralData.objects.filter(examination__number_of_examination=1, examination__patient=get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')))
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The detail page loads only the Patient model (...) is it possible to load other models in the template ?"

You don't "load" models "in the template", you pass them (or any other object you want) to the template's context - most often from your view code but actually from whereever you want to render a template. And yes of course you can pass just whatever you want, populating the template context is up to you.

> The query which will work is:
>     `Generaldata.objects.filter(examination__number_of_examination=1, examination__patient=Testpatient)`
>
> but this is in the wrong order.

Why is it "in the wrong order" ??? And if that query works what prevents you from using it ?

NB : if you're using generic `DetailView`, adding extra context is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting code in comments - and be more specific, "doesn't work" is about the most useless possible description of a problem. Also you obviously want to filter your `Examination` models on the current patient.